# Number of divisions using trial division to factorize the product of two k-digit primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I'm more of a programmer than a Mathematician so please bear with me if my question is too trivial.

I am looking up RSA specifically the key generation bit. Using Trial division, I know that it would take roughly `(2*(n^0.5))/ln n` divisions to find the factors of n.

However I'd like to represent this in a generalized manner i.e. how many divisions would it take to factorize the product of two k-digit primes ?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that both primes are approximately $5\times 10^k$. This is in fact the worst-case scenario for trial division. How long trial division will take depends on how exactly you implement it. If you have a table of all primes with up to $5\times 10^k$, then the number of trial divisions will be equal to the number of primes up to $5\times 10^k$, which is 
$$\pi(5\times 10^k)\approx\frac{5\times 10^k}{\ln 5\times 10^k}=\frac{5\times 10^k}{\ln 5 + k\ln 10}$$
with the approximation following from the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). However, if you do not have such a table (which is likely the case if $k$ is large enough for the primes to be used for RSA) then you will need to perform $5\times 10^k$ trial divisions.